# is whitelisting preg_replace() inputs?

Tags: php, html, input, xss, whitelist

What does whitelisting involve for inputs to prevent html and xss injection?

From what I gather preg_replace with regular expression is a good start. What else?

Comment: What actually do you want to whitelist?

Comment: If you want to clean HTML input (against xss), then `HTMLPurifier` is sometimes the better alternative over `strip_tags` or a cleansing regex.

Comment: Properly escape on output (depending on context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to sanitize output than input. Apply the correct escaping every time your data passes from one context to the next. For example, apply [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) when data is passed to the database (if you are using the MySQLi extension), apply [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) when you output the data as HTML and so on.